# AutoHotKey - How to take a screenshot and to paste it to a *.jpg file?

Tags: autohotkey

How to take a screenshot in Windows 8 and to paste it to a *.jpg file using AutoHotKey script? I want my custom key combination and folder for images

Comment: see https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/91585-screen-capture-using-only-ahk-no-3rd-party-software-required/

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Yeah, it's a mess of 32 64 bit incompatibility, from looking at the forums people mostly use http://www.irfanview.com/ it has a nice cli. Is that an option for you?

Comment: __ I  don't  use  it __

Comment: So? Any software you currently use you weren't using before you needed it to solve a problem you had.

Comment: Most of the solutions to this issue rely on automating the paste/save in Microsoft Paint (https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/56656-save-screenshot-directly-to-file-the-cool-newbie-way/). Writing image data in the clipboard directly to file isn't something AutoHotkey does very well.

Answer (score 3):

```
{CustomKey}::   ;image saved in Pictures/Screenshots folder by default
Send #{PrintScreen}
Return
```

The images are saved as png; can then be converted to jpg and moved to another directory.

Tested in Win 10.
Might work in Win 8 too.

Comment: Works in Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 2):

Another question similar asked here: 
https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/63742-how-to-save-a-screen-shot-with-ahk/

Problem was that saved file was blank. In my case, the file turned out to be all grey.
Reason was that FileAppend saved as text file.

To save screenshot image taken with PrintScrn button:

```
; Send {PrintScreen}
FileAppend %ClipboardAll%, FileName.raw, UTF-8

; This can be read back to memory with:
FileRead, Clipboard, *c FileName.raw

; image can also be converted/compressed to save space.
; I already had ffmpeg, so put this:
Run %ComSpec% /c "ffmpeg.exe -f rawvideo -pixel_format rgb32 -s 2256x1504 -i FileName.raw -vf hflip -vf vflip output.png"
```

Tested on Win 10.

Comment: The file is being saved, but it couldn't be open. What if I am making multiple screenshots at the same time, will it rewrite the existing one or create a new file?

Comment: For multiple screenshots, specify different filenames, eg. in a loop with sequential suffix. For same filenames, previous file will be overwritten.
Files are saved in UTF/RAW format; can be opened with image editors/viewers that support it. 
Saved files may also be compressed/converted to other formats eg. above code compresses it with ffmpeg to PNG, to save space & compatible with more viewers eg. web browsers.

Comment: Now it works without any other changes of the code. I've noticed that it creates .png files in the default screenshot folder and automatically increment the file names there, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might try using the Gdip_All.ahk library.  I found a maintained version of it at: https://github.com/mmikeww/AHKv2-Gdip/blob/master/Gdip_All.ahk

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiKwDHa8-svJgesEx_8cB9ccXRYT-w?e=ErfLUb   I wrote it for making screenshots in Windows, you can specify the image location in .ini file (and name) and associate any key to run it. The second part of a name consists of the current date and time, so you can make a distinct screenshot every second.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Irfan View installed you can use this:

```
run('"C:\Program Files\IrfanView\i_view64.exe" /capture=0 "/convert=path_to_file.png" /jpgq=95')
```

You can also specify format or quality and include process name, time or other staff, for example:

```
dir          := 'D:\screenshots'
name         := winGetProcessName('A') '  ' a_YYYY '-' a_MM '-' a_DD '  ' a_hour '-' a_min '-' a_sec

format       := 'png'
quality_jpeg := 95

run('"C:\Program Files\IrfanView\i_view64.exe" /capture=0 "/convert=' dir '\' name '.' format '" /jpgq=' quality_jpeg)
```

You can check Irfan View command line options in the program help or [here](https://www.etcwiki.org/wiki/IrfanView_Command_Line_Options).

You can also search some other programs that can silently make screenshots using command line options. If you find another good one let me know.